# Hi, while i deploy spring app to heroku i get error, does anybody know how to fix this?

Tags: spring-boot, heroku

while i deploy spring app to heroku i get such error, does anybody know how to fix this?

after: git push heroku master
command i get such error

tried updating maven as well

```
       [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project mentofit: Fatal error compiling: invalid flag: --release -> [Help 1]
       [ERROR] 
       [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
       [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
       [ERROR] 
       [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
       [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
       ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven
       We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,
       please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/
       Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.
       Push failed
```

my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.javangar</groupId>
    <artifactId>mentofit</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>mentofit</name>
    <description>Mental Fit</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

(my post is mostly code warning)   (my post is mostly code warning)  (my post is mostly code warning)